# iphone simulator shows blank screen

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

When I run iPhone simulator (SDK 3.1.3, MacOS 10.5.7) **standalone** or from XCode - I see only black screen.
In the console I see a lot of:

```
"invalid pixel format"
"invalid context"
```

Any ideas what happens?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if 3.1.4 is a typo and you mean 3.1.3 or not, but the latest iPhone SDK is only supported on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard.

Probably explains why it doesn't work on 10.5 Leopard.

Comment: So in that case you need to upgrade to Mac OS X 10.6. iPhone SDK 3.1.3 is only supported on Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: I upgraded to SDK 3.1.3 a couple of months ago while I was still on Leopard.  I only converted to Snow Leopard a week ago.  So SDK 3.1.3 and Leopard are compatible.

Comment: http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/development_tools/iphonesdk.html

it support 10.5.7 or later

Comment: Since the 3.2 SDK was released Apple have removed the links to 3.1.3 SDK from the dev website. So I can't check what I actually saw. I never trust the descriptions of things on the Apple Downloads site, as I've had apps of my own on there and the descriptions sometimes didn't match with what I provided. Either way, if you believe it should be supported on 10.5, then you should probably contact Apple Support and see if they can help.